# What's the best practice for linking to/from guest posts on other blogs?

Tags: blog, nofollow

When writing a guest blog for a site, I include a link back to my site - an inbound link.

If I were to write a post on my blog publicising my guest post, that would mean there were reciprocal links, thus cancelling each other out, correct?

If I made the link (on my blog) back to the guest post nofollow, would that cancel the effect, meaning I still get link juice from the guest post?

Further down the line if the site I posted on as a guest wanted to write a post for my site, what is the best way for me to prevent re-introducing the reciprocal link problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure links are relevant and useful. Don't be too concerned about linking in or out. Yes, links in are important but you will never be penalized for linking out - however, always make sure that it's worthwhile. For example, if you sell shoes then link to information about shoes. If you sell shoes, don't link to a site about computer repair!